# Proof of Schwarz lemma using Maximum Modulus Principle

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading wiki's [Schwarz lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma)
, where it's proved using [Maximum modulus principl](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Maximum_modulus_principle):

> **Statement**: Let $\mathbf {D} =\{z:|z|<1\}$ be the open unit disk in the
> complex plane $\mathbb {C}$  centered at the origin, and let
> $\displaystyle f:\mathbf {D} \rightarrow \mathbb {C} $ be a
> holomorphic map such that $f(0)=0$ and $|f(z)|\leq 1$ on $\mathbf{D}$.
>
> Then $|f(z)|\leq |z|$ for all $\displaystyle z\in \mathbf {D} $, and
> $|f'(0)| \leq 1$.
>
> Moreover, if $|f(z)|=|z|$ for some non-zero $z$ or $|f'(0)| = 1$, then
> $f(z)=az$ for some $a \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|a|=1$.
>
> **Proof**:
>
> The proof is a straightforward application of the maximum modulus
> principle on the function
>
> $$g(z)={\begin{cases}{\frac  {f(z)}{z}}\,&{\mbox{if }}z\neq
> > 0\\f'(0)&{\mbox{if }}z=0,\end{cases}}$$ which is holomorphic on the
> whole of $D$, including at the origin (because $f$ is differentiable
> at the origin and fixes zero). Now if $D_{r}=\{z:|z|\leq r\}$
> denotes the closed disk of radius $r$ centered at the origin,
> then the maximum modulus principle implies that, for $r<1$
> , given any $z\in D_{r}$, there exists $z_{r}$ on
> the boundary of $D_{r}$ such that
>
> $$|g(z)|\leq |g(z_{r})|=\frac {|f(z_{r})|}{|z_{r}|}\leq \frac {1}{r}.$$
>
> As $r\rightarrow 1$ we get $|g(z)|\leq 1$.
>
> Moreover, suppose that $|f(z)|=|z|$ for some non-zero $z\in D$, or
> $|f'(0)| = 1$. Then, $ |g(z)|=1$ at some point of $D$. So by the
> maximum modulus principle, $g(z)$ is equal to a constant
> $a$ such that $|a|=1$. Therefore,
> $f(z)=az$, as desired.

What I don't understand is this line:

> ... the maximum modulus principle implies that, for
> $r<1$, given any $z\in D_{r}$, there exists $z_{r}$ on
> the boundary of $D_{r}$ such that
>
> $$|g(z)|\leq |g(z_{r})|=\frac {|f(z_{r})|}{|z_{r}|}\leq \frac {1}{r}.$$

Why so? The [Maximum modulus principl](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Maximum_modulus_principle) only guarantees that $z$ wouldn't be a local maximum for $|g(z)|$, i.e. there exists a $z_r$ s.t.
$$|g(z)|\leq |g(z_{r})|$$
but MMP does not say $z_r$ is at the boundary or $D_r$.

Please enlighten me.

Comment: The maximum modulus principle guarantees that $g$ does not have a maximum on any open connected set (on which $g$ is defined) if $g$ is not constant.

Comment: @Caffeine ah I see.. if no such $z_r$ exist on $D_r$ then inside $D_r$ there is a maximum